# The List functor

Tags: category-theory

I have been reading some notes on Category Theory. One question that is posed is to verify the definition of $\operatorname{List}$ is a functor...

$\operatorname{List}(g \circ f) = (\operatorname{List} g) \circ (\operatorname{List} f)$

I can see this makes sense in programming terms whereby a function $f$ is mapped to a function $\operatorname{map} f$ but how do you prove this in a mathematically rigorous way?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that in mathematics, this would probably be called the free monoid functor. Also, while the equation you give is valid, I'm not sure that's a sufficient mathematical definition of a functor.

Comment: Functoriality states that identities are preserved too

Answer (score 5):

The property in your question is that a functor preserves morphism composition between categories. In functional programming, the `map` function provides the morphism-mapping part of the List functor. This property can be proved by induction over the structure of the list datatype, using the definition of `map`.

I'll use Haskell here as its syntax is fairly clean. `map` is defined:

```
 map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
 map f [] = []
 map f (x:xs) = (f x) : (map f xs)
```

The property we want to prove is:

```
 map (g . f) = (map g) . (map f)
```

We will proceed by reducing the left-hand side (LHS) and right-hand side (RHS)
of this equation, for the base and inductive cases, and showing them equal.

- Base case: `[]`

  On the LHS:

  ```
   map (g . f) []
  = []                     {map defn. [1st case]}
  ```

  On the RHS:

  ```
    ((map g) . (map f)) [] 
  = (map g) []             {map defn. [1st case], on the right of .}      
  = []                     {map defn. [1st case]}
  ```
- Inductive case: `x:xs`. The *inductive hypothesis* is that

  ```
  (map (g . f)) xs = ((map g) . (map f)) xs
  ```

  On the LHS:

  ```
    map (g . f) (x:xs)
  = ((g . f) x) : (map (g . f) xs)         {map defn. [2nd case]}
  ```

  On the RHS:

  ```
    ((map g) . (map f)) (x:xs)     
  = (map g) ((f x) : (map f xs))            {map defn. [2nd case], on right of .}
  = (g (f x)) : (map g (map f xs))          {map defn. [second case]}
  = ((g . f) x) : (((map g) . (map f)) xs)  {definition of composition .}
  = ((g . f) x) : (map (g . f) xs)          {by inductive hypothesis}
  ```

This completes both cases of the inductive proof for the preservation of morphism composition by `map` for the List functor.